# Как парсить всплывающие окна браузера?

Tags: python, парсер

Как вводить свои данные, если на сайте аутентификация происходит с помощью всплывающего окна? как вообще парсить такое?
Буду рад любой информации, спасибо

python 3

[image: окно]

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/248559/

Comment: Конкретно это - [базовая аутентификация](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Используйте в качестве URL схему `http://user:password@192.168.1.254`. Через селениум такое не ловится, насколько я знаю.